# (IN WEBAPPS FOLDER) why is able to read PHP code from a subfolder but not able to read PHP from dist(angular rendered project))

Tags: php, mysql, angular, tomcat

I am making a full angular app with front(`angular`) and back(`php` and `MySQL`). I am using a tomcat server where I place a dist folder on webapps and its okay, able to run the front because I see the webapp, but when I want to login or database stuff it gives an error because I suppose it is something blocking it (Already made a connection on workbench that connect successfully) and if I try to run a normal php script from the server to communicate to DB it works...so php its working on tomcat and I cannot communicate to the database...

so my tomcat is able to interpret php, angular working properly but when I want to work on angular to make request to the server it falls.

> SOLVED:
> Okay I will explain how I fixed; the final problem was about how `angular` and `cors` work together because it doesn't let you accept your request wherever it comes just like that, you need at least a few cooperation from the server; so in my case I was using Tomcat9 which is able to make CORS native filtering:

```html
<!-- This code goes on : apache-tomcat/conf/web.xml -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then its time to create a `proxy.conf.json` with:

```
{
    "/webAppName/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/webAppFolder",
        "secure": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/posts": ""
        },
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And finally add this script to your dependencies:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

And the make npm start and open the server and voilá.
This trick works for me.

This is a `tomcat9`, using `angular7`, `php7`, `mysql8`.

Comment: _“it gives an error”_ - WHAT error? Be specific.

Comment: Already edited, thank you.

Comment: Well if there was a problem creating the database connection, you should find “Failed to connect: …” somewhere in the response. (For an AJAX background request, checks the response in browser dev tools, network panel.) `ERROR TypeError: "err.error is null"` could mean that angular expected you to return an error in a specific format, probably a JSON object that actually contains an `error` property. By just having your PHP script die with a custom error message, you’d then be causing this subsequent error on the client side …

Comment: I am agree, the connection to the database its okey from the workbench, but i dont know why my php scrips that are located in foldel ´app´ doesnt want to work, also it gives me this: 
ERROR OK core.js:7187:19
    Angular 4
        defaultErrorLogger
        handleError
        next
        schedulerFn
    RxJS 5
        __tryOrUnsub
        next
        _next
        next
        next
    Angular 11
        emit
        onHandleError
        invoke
        run
        runOutsideAngular
        onHandleError
        handleError
        runTask, invokeTask, invoke, timer

Comment: Also in local on localhost:4200 works perfect, when i want to do the same on tomcat in localhost:8080 doesnt wont to comunicate.

Comment: Please go check what the request to your PHP script actually gets answered with as I asked you to, in the network panel.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, but here it is the stacktrace from the error y get on the browser console; XHR GET http://localhost/apiPHP/read.php; then; ERROR Unknown Error core.js:7187:19. PHP scripts get answered when i go for example; http://localhost:8080/apiPHP/readNominas.php it gets the values, but if i want to do the same in angular there is no chance